# spring 4 mvc aop not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

pom like this

```
<!-- Spring MVC <spring-framework.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- aspectj <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

aspect like this

```
 @Aspect public class RestfulAspect {
@Before("methodPointcut()")
public void beforeImpl() {
    System.out.println("  Before Done ");
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.smart.testspring.Repository.BookRespository.selectAll(..))")
public void methodPointcut() {

    System.out.println(" Pointcut ");
}}
```

applicationContext like this

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
 <bean id="bookBean" class="com.smart.testspring.Repository.BookRespository" />
<bean id="aspectBean" class="com.smart.testspring.aop.RestfulAspect" />
```

and i  try `<!--<mvc:annotation-driven />-->` but can't find controller.so i did not add `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

above is my project, but aspect don't have work, who helped me to check out my problems.

Comment: BookRespository class like this

@Component
public class BookRespository {

    public BookRespository() {
    }

    public String selectAll(String param) {
        return "selectbookall";
    }

    public void selectAll1() {
        System.out.println("void");
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that the MVC container is a application child container, so the AOP configuration is moved to the mvc-config configuration file, it's worked.